# How to write these queries? Used in ElasticSearch and c#

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

```
var query = new { query = new { term = new { Name = "banana" } } };
```

what is this?

need to know how to write these queries... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NEST you can do this by:

```
client.Search<YourTypeGoesHere>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(t => t.Name, "banana")));
```